# IRC client while loop and scanf()

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scanf, irc

this is my first question here. So, I’m trying to make IRC client in C. All information from server goes to buffer and with while loop I print everything to terminal.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char \
    *bot_owner = "Arbarbarabas",
    *nick = "Abuditaragas",
    *serv = "irc.omnitel.net",
    *chan = "#any";

int main() {
    int ret;
    char buf[512];
    char msg[100];
    pid_t pid;
#ifdef _WIN32
    SOCKET sock;
    struct WSAData* wd = (struct WSAData*)malloc(sizeof(struct WSAData));
    ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), wd);
    free(wd);
    if (ret) { puts("Error loading Windows Socket API"); return 1; }
#else
    int sock;
#endif
    struct addrinfo hints, *ai;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    if (ret = getaddrinfo(serv, "6667", &hints, &ai)) {
        puts(gai_strerror(ret));
        return 1;
    }
    sock = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
    if (ret = connect(sock, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen)) {
        puts(gai_strerror(ret));
        return 1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    sprintf(buf, "USER %s 0 * :%s\r\n", nick, bot_owner);
    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    sprintf(buf, "NICK %s\r\n", nick);
    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);


    while(1){

        scanf("+inute %s", msg);
        sprintf(buf, "PRIVMSG %s :Someone just spoke to me! %s \r\n", chan, msg);
        send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);

            while (recv(sock, buf, 512, 0) > 0) {
                fputs(buf, stdout);
                if (!strncmp(buf, "PING ", 5)) {
                    buf[1] = 'O';
                    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                    sprintf(buf, "PRIVMSG %s :Asked me PING :O \r\n", chan);
                    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                }
                    if (buf[0] != ':') continue;
                    if (!strncmp(strchr(buf, ' ') + 1, "001", 3)) {
                    sprintf(buf, "MODE %s +B\r\nJOIN %s\r\n", nick, chan);
                    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                } else if (!strncmp(strchr(buf, ' ') + 1, "PRIVMSG", 7)) {
                    if (strncmp(strchr(buf + 1, ':') + 1, nick, strlen(nick))) continue;
                    sprintf(buf, "PRIVMSG %s :Someone just spoke to me!\r\n", chan);
                    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
                }
            }
    }

    WSACleanup();

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to not stop while loop and write message at the same moment?

Edit: added whole code.

Comment: I suggest you look into more socket server tutorials, and read more about non-blocking sockets and how to poll for input instead.

Comment: It looks as though you have omitted something from your sample code -- the braces and indentation are mismatched at line 8. Can you please show us your actual code?

Comment: Thanks for answers, I added whole code of program. If it’s possible please explain me everything like for dummy, because it’s my first time with C and with sockets. I have task and I should finish it as fast as it’s possible.

Comment: Nobody's going to do your work for you. Here's a good start when it comes to reading : http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: I'm not asking to do my work, all what I want is that somebody explain me how to use loop and scanf at the same moment... They should work independent from each other.Or I'm thinking too hard how to solve this problem.

Comment: There's undefined behaviour here. `recv` doesn't null terminate your array. You need to store it's return value somewhere, since that's the number of bytes recieved, and give that number to `fwrite` instead of using `fputs` which assumes null termination.